# Why is clojure-mode replacing fn with some curly f character?

Tags: emacs, clojure

I've just started using emacs starter kit & clojure-mode.  Now, when I type or paste '`(fn`' into a buffer in clojure mode, the '`fn`' characters get replaced in the window with a slightly curly lower case f.  The buffer is saved correctly, but it's extremely annoying, especially as I discovered the feature the hard way - puzzling over someone's 'impossible' code snippet and editing it down to a one-liner before light dawned.  Any idea why it does this, or more importantly, how to switch it off?

Comment: Dammit - it's doing it with lambda in common-lisp-mode as well.  So I guess this is emacs starter kit rather than clojure-mode.

Comment: Personally I really like it! It's striking visually and makes it more obvious that it's a lambda. I'd be asking a different question: how can easily add that feature to all my emacses?

Comment: @Markc: I'm with you. I love it.

Comment: The lambda I can see the point of.  Sending 'fn' to almost-but-not-quite 'f', not so much.

Comment: I just discovered it the hard way too. Is there any place where we could edit the symbol? For instance to use a lambda instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question.  It's in starter-kit-lisp.el.  Look for the line starting `(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode`.

Comment: I had to comment out the lines containing the function `esk-pretty-fn` and also `(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'esk-pretty-fn)` in both `starter-kit-lisp.el` and `starter-kit-lisp-autoloads.el`

Answer (score 6):

It can be turned off by adding the following line to your `init.el` after loading starter-kit-lisp.

```
(remove-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'esk-pretty-fn)
```

Then re-load Emacs for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

In emacs live you can disable this behaviour with the following:

In `~/.emacs.d/packs/live/clojure-pack/config/clojure-conf.el` comment these lines:

```
;;(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
;;  '(font-lock-add-keywords
;;    'clojure-mode `(("(\\(fn\\)[\[[:space:]]"
;;                     (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
;;                                               (match-end 1) "λ")
;;                               nil))))))
;;
;;(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
;;  '(font-lock-add-keywords
;;    'clojure-mode `(("\\(#\\)("
;;                     (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
;;                                               (match-end 1) "ƒ")
;;                               nil))))))
;;
;;(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
;;  '(font-lock-add-keywords
;;    'clojure-mode `(("\\(#\\){"
;;                     (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
;;                                               (match-end 1) "∈")
;;                               nil))))))
```

Restart emacs and there are no more fancy symbols.