# why is emacs replacing fn with question mark?

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm using clojure-mode + nrepl + paredit + lein-swank.

every time I use anonymous functions in clojure, (fn[x] (+ x 1)),
it is automatically replaced by ? (question mark).

- How do I turn this off ?
- what is the reason for this ?

Comment: Here's a guess: you have some code that tries to replace each instance of `fn` with `λ`,
but it doesn't work because your Emacs is old or something. Start with `emacs -q` and load your stuff one by one until you see the one that does this.

Comment: What is your Emacs version, and the font you are using for Emacs?  Do you use Starter Kit or something similar?

Comment: The failure to display λ is likely the problem. Emacs has been unicode complete for a very long time now, it is likely he just doesn't have a font installed that would display this character. @Attilah are you a Linux user? if so there is something you can install called unifont that helps other fonts fill in missing characters. Also you can disable the action, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920786/why-is-clojure-mode-replacing-fn-with-some-curly-f-character)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments this is almost certainly a font problem preventing the ƒ from displaying correctly. You can turn this feature off by putting

```
(remove-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'esk-pretty-fn)
```

into your init.el file or equivalent, or paste it into the `*scratch*` buffer and hit <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-e</kbd> with the cursor at the end of the line.